# Docker log formatting

Tags: python-3.x, docker, logging, docker-compose, string-formatting

I have a Docker container for my application with REST API.

I want to check what happened via `docker logs`, but it prints in the strange format:

```
docker logs -f 2b46ac8629f5
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:9002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
172.18.0.5 - - [03/Mar/2019 13:53:38] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type      
("\x16\x03\x01\x00«\x01\x00\x00§\x03\x03\x0euçÍ'ïá\x98\x12\\W5¥Ä\x01\x08")

172.18.0.5 - - [03/Mar/2019 13:53:38] "«§uçÍ'ïá\W5¥µuìz«Ôw48À,À0Ì©Ì¨ÌªÀ+À/À$À(kÀ#À'gÀ" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Is it possible to fix these strings somehow?

**UPDATE:**

Part of my docker-compose file looks like:

```
api:
  container_name: api
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  ports:
    - "9002:9002"
  volumes:
    - ./myapp.co.cert:/usr/src/app/myapp.co.cert
    - /usr/src/app/myapp/static
    - ./myapp.co.key:/usr/src/appmyapp.co.key
  depends_on:
    - postgres
```

Docker file of `web` container looks:

```
cat web/Dockerfile 
# For better understanding of what is going on please follow this link:
# https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/f12c2df135aef8c3f645d90aae582b2c65dbc3b5/3.6/jessie/onbuild/Dockerfile

FROM python:3.6.4-onbuild

# Start myapp API.
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

`api.py` starts Flask app using Python 3.6

Comment: The content of the logs is controlled by the software running in the container, not docker. Please provide the ```Dockerfile``` and/or ```docker-compose.yml``` file you are using to start your containers to help us help you.

Comment: @SteveBoyd, I've updated my question.

Comment: This is not related to Docker. The `api.py` is responsible for the log format.

Comment: Uneducated guess: you're trying to connect to `https://localhost:9002/` but the application isn't actually configured for a TLS service and is expecting plain HTTP.  Without seeing your `api.py` or knowing how you triggered this error, that's just a guess.